# How can you increment a gsub() replacement string?

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Assume a data frame has many columns that all say “bonus”.  The goal is to rename each bonus column uniquely with an appended number.  Example data:

```
string  <- c("bonus", "bonus", "bonus", "bonus")
string
[1] "bonus" "bonus" "bonus" "bonus"
```

Desired column name output:

```
[1] "bonus1" "bonus2" "bonus3" "bonus4"
```

Assume you don’t know how many bonus columns there are be so you cannot simply paste from 1 to that number of columns to each bonus column name.

The following approach works but seems inelegant and seems too hard-coded:

```
bonus.count  <- nrow(count(grep(pattern = "bonus", x = string)))
string.numbered  <- paste0(string, seq(from = 1, to = bonus.count, 1)
```

How can the gsub function (or another regex-based function) substitute an incremented number?  Along the lines of

```
string.gsub.numbered  <- gsub(pattern = "bonus", replacement = "bonusincremented by one until no more bonuses", x = string)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `gsub` can't run any sort of function over each result, but using `regexpr` and `regmatches` makes this pretty easy

```
string  <- c("bonus", "bonus", "bonus", "bonus")
m <- regexpr("bonus",string)
regmatches(string,m) <- paste0(regmatches(string,m), 1:length(m))
string
# [1] "bonus1" "bonus2" "bonus3" "bonus4"
```

The nice part is that `regmatches` allows for assignment so it's easy to swap out the matched values.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Using `string` defined in the question we can write:

```
paste0(string, seq_along(string))
```

**2)** If what you really have is something like this:

```
string2 <- "As a bonus we got a bonus coupon."
```

and you want to change that to `"As a bonus1 we got a bonus2 coupon."` then `gsubfn` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) can do that.  Below, the `fun` method of the `p` proto object will be applied to each occurrence of `"bonus"` with `count` automatically incremented.  THe proto object `p` automatically saves the state of `count` between matches to allow this:

```
library(gsubfn)
string2 <- "As a bonus we got a bonus coupon." # test data

p <- proto(fun = function(this, x) paste0(x, count))
gsubfn("bonus", p, string2)
```

giving:

```
[1] "As a bonus1 we got a bonus2 coupon."
```

There are additional exxamples in the [proto vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/vignettes/gsubfn.pdf).